# NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new on sign up with Devise and Refinery Cms 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, refinerycms

I am trying to Sign up on my app, I get this error

```
NoMethodError in Devise::Registrations#new 
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">


undefined method `user_registration_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fb0bc0dc220>
```

My rake routes output

```
                       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
            new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
               user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                         reg GET    /reg(.:format)                 reg#regl
                    refinery        /                              Refinery::Core::Engine

// much refinery routes
```

I have already restarted Webrick and performed db:reset db:migrate
Also, when I am trying to access resource with console on web page I get

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fb0c2b683a0>
```

here is my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users 




  # This line mounts Refinery's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to the root URL of your application will go to Refinery::PagesController#home.
  # If you would like to change where this extension is mounted, simply change the
  # configuration option `mounted_path` to something different in config/initializers/refinery/core.rb




  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Refinery relies on it being the default of "refinery"
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: Refinery::Core.mounted_path



end
```

Comment: What is the NoMethodError? Is that the actual output from your webpage or terminal?

Comment: this is from Webpage

Comment: Gotcha. Usually with Rails an error like this will show a highlighted (red) line of code, or a method name, or a class name, causing or related to the error. It would be unusual in recent releases or Rails to only get a `NoMethodError` with no other information. Do you see anything like that?

Comment: yeah undefined method `user_registration_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fb0bc0dc220>

Comment: Can you post the contents of your routes.rb file?

Comment: If you have `registrations_controller` handling the sign_ups then change it to `devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }`

Comment: Nope. Thats fresh after installation. No custom controllers

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days s finaly slove it . add

```
Devise.setup do |config| config.router_name = :main_app end
```

in config/initializers/devise.rb